# What does $\frac12(D_{2p}\times D_{2p})$ mean in group theory?

Tags: group-theory, notation

Reading a thesis, I have come across the (unexplained) notation
$$\frac{1}{2}(D_{2p}\times D_{2p})\cong (p\times p):2,$$
where $D_{2p}$ is a dihedral group.   What does this "$\frac12$" notation mean?  For what groups $G$ does $\frac12 G$ make sense?

Comment: This gets covered somewhat in _The Symmetries Of Things_ - there's a natural normal $C_2$ subgroup (IIRC it's the subgroup generated by the element $\langle i, i\rangle$ where $i$ is a reflection in $D_{2p}$, but I don't have my copy to hand); your group is the quotient of $D_{2p}\times D_{2p}$ by that group.

Comment: $(p \times p):2$ is ATLAS notation and you can deduce the intended meaning from the fact that all other possible interpretations would be denoted differently, such as $(p:2) \times p$ or $2p \times p$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fleshing out my comment above: the notation $\frac1f(G\times H)$ actually appears in the book *On Quaternions and Octonions* (chapter 4.3, "Naming the Groups").  The explanation there says:

> $\frac1f[\![L\times R]\!]$ consists of the elements $[\![l,r]\!]$ for
>   which $l\in 2L, r\in 2R$, and $l^\alpha=r^\beta$, where $\alpha$ and
>   $\beta$ are two homomorphisms from these onto the same finite group
>   $F$ of order $f$.

(Here the $2$ in $2L$ and $2R$ refers to quaternion groups and the fact that the quaternions form a double cover; it's not meant to mean that these groups are e.g. $2.L$). Just as the notation suggests, the order of $\frac1f[\![L\times R]\!]$ is $\dfrac{\left|L\right|\cdot \left|R\right|}{f}$).

**EDIT:** Note that unlike what the comments (and a previous version of this answer) suggested, this is *not* just a quotient of the product group by an element $[\![i_L,i_R]\!]$, where $i_L$ and $i_R$ are elements of order two in the respective groups.  (This would pick out e.g. all the elements where $l$ is not a reflection.)  Instead, it's in some sense the opposite; it consists of all pairs $[\![l,r]\!]$ where $l$ and $r$ have the same 'parity' — for instance, in the case where $L=R=D_{2p}$, those pairs where either both $l$ and $r$ are reflections or where neither is.  It's not too hard to see that this is a subgroup, since the property that $l$ and $r$ both have the same parity (more generically, are in the same homomorphism class) is preserved under group multiplication.

The notation $(p\times p):2$ appears in chapter 16 of *The Symmetries of Things*; it refers to the split extension of the group $H=p\times p$ (i.e. $C_p\times C_p$) by a group $2$ ($C_2$), with the nontrivial element $c$ of $2$ acting on elements $h\in H$ of the other group by $c^{-1}hc=h^{-1}$.  This can naturally be thought of as the *dihedralization* of $p\times p$; of course the dihedralization of $C_p$, i.e. $p:2$, is just $D_{2p}$.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  I was having trouble understanding the earlier version, as $D_{2p}\times D_{2p}$ has no normal order $2$ subgroups for odd primes $p$.

Comment: @James You're very welcome - I realized just before bed last night that I was 'quotienting out' incorrectly; I should have realized from the trouble I was having making it equal $(p\times p):2$.